# laravel: Undefined variable: productsALL views\shop.blade.php

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.7

hi m working to show products into a seprate shop.blade.php page but page is not opening and it gives error Undefined variable: productsALL, 
the code is here:

```
@foreach($productsALL as $product)
<!--some html-->
<img src="{{ asset('images/backend_images/products/small/'.$product->image) }}" alt="IMG-PRODUCT">
{{ $product->product_name }}
@endforeach
```

here is its route:

```
Route::get('shop', function () {
return view('shop');
});
```

and this is ShopController:

```
public function shop()
{
    $productsALL = Product::get();
    return view('shop')->with(compact('productsALL'));
}
```

anyone would prefer to provide its solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Route is wrong.
Actually, your Route isn't link with your Controller, you need to link with put "Namespace@functionName".

Try this :

```
Route::get('shop', 'ShopController@shop');
```

[Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#named-routes)